# Significado del prefijo "para-" en palabras compuestas

Tags: definiciones

¿Cuál sería el siginifcado o qué debo entender sobre el prefijo **para-** en palabras compuestas?
Por ejemplo:

> - **Para**médico
> - **Para**militar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Para-' indica que algo no es, pero se parece a, otra cosa.

Un paramédico no es un médico, es un enfermero, que se parece a un médico. Esta palabra no se utiliza comúnmente en castellano.

Un paramilitar no es un militar, pero se comporta de la misma manera y tiene una organización, entrenamiento y armamento similares.

Una parafarmacia no es una farmacia, pero vende productos similares que también podemos encontrar en las verdaderas farmacias.

Comment: A lo mejor por ser yo de latinoamerica si me es muy comun escuchar paramilitares en el caso de colombia y mexico

Comment: 'paramilitares' sí existe, 'paramédicos' es la que dije que no se usa en español, porque tenemos enfermero.

Comment: Tengo entendido que "paramédico" se utiliza para designar a los técnicos de emergencias, no a los enfermeros.

Comment: @MikMik En el español en general no existe 'Paramédico' con ese sentido. Son médicos de emergencias, o enfermeros de emergencias. El DRAE lo recoge solamente para Chile y El Salvador: http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=param%C3%A9dico

Comment: @envite Lo sé; quería decir que "enfermero" no es lo que mejor describe el trabajo de los "paramedics".

Answer (score 5):

[Según la RAE](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?key=para) significa:

> (Del gr. παρα-).
>   1. pref. Significa 'junto a', 'al margen de', 'contra'. Paracronismo, paráfrasis, paradoja.

La misma información en la [Wikipedia](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Para_(Prefijo)).

Comment: gracias.. parece como hace rato no uso el espanol para comunicarme se me habia olvidado la palabra prefijo que es el uso del `para`...me acorde del colegio :)